# Export HTML to DocX with external Stylesheet

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm using [QuillJs](https://quilljs.com/) to permit users edit text in my project, it was super easy to implement it in my web app(I'm using Laravel for the back-end, and HTML/CSS/JS for front-end), and i'd like to add function to export the customized text to Docx and PDF, and there's the problem, [QuillJs](https://quilljs.com/) use an external stylesheet to build the edited text, so some parts of the text when it's exported don't show any of the style I've tried export it with [PHPWord](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and Vanilla JavaScript, both of them seems to only allow inline style.
My JS function:

```
const Foo = () => {
    var header = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' " +
            "xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' " +
            "xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>" +
            "<head><meta charset='utf-8'>" +
            "<link type=\"text/css\" href=\"https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">" +
            "</head><body>";
    var footer = "</body></html>";
    var body = document.querySelector('.ql-editor').innerHTML;
    var sourceHTML = header + body + footer;
    var source = 'data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(sourceHTML);
    // console.log(source);
    var fileDownload = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(fileDownload);
    fileDownload.href = source;
    fileDownload.download = 'document.doc';
    fileDownload.click();
    document.body.removeChild(fileDownload);
  }
```

You can see that I've tried to add `<link type=\"text/css\" href=\"https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">`
So, my question there's a way to export it with the styles, or there's another text editor but with inline style(open-source plz)?

Edit 1: I've tried to add a `` var style = (`<style> css ...</style>`) ``;

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, I've solved my problem in a simple way, changing the editor framework. I've tried [Froala Editor](https://www.froala.com/) and [QuillJs](https://quilljs.com/), both of them when I exported to Docx didn't came with the style, so I searched for another one, them I've found [Summernote](https://summernote.org/), an open-source WYSIWYG editor with **INLINE STYLE**, now I can export my Docx files with style.